# Is there a global option to enable Dinero.js strict currency format checking?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dinero.js

Using the latest Dinero, in the codebase I'm recently in charge with there's an absence of standard how they write 'usd'. As a result, this happens:

```js
Dinero({
    currency: 'usd' as 'USD',
    amount: 1
}).add(Dinero({
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 1,
}))
```

Throws `You must provide a Dinero instance with the same currency`. For Dinero, 'usd' and 'USD' aren't the same currencies it seems.

Is there a way to either make Dinero throw when a wrong currency is supplied? `usd` in lowercase is presumably a wrong one because in DefinitelyTyped the currency type includes only `USD`.

If not throw, then at least automatically convert it to uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such an option, and it's not in the plan at the moment of writing this (https://github.com/dinerojs/dinero.js/issues/637).

The solution could be restricting import from 'dinero.js' in eslint

```
"rules": {
        "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
          "paths": [{
            "name": "dinero.js",
            "message": "please import dinero from utils/money"
          }]
        }]
      }
```

...

```
export const Dinero = (...[opts]: Parameters<typeof DineroOriginal>) => {
  if (opts?.currency && opts.currency.toUpperCase() !== opts.currency) {
    // don't convert, but fail-fast
    throw new Error(`Currency ${opts.currency} is not uppercase`);
  }
  return DineroOriginal(opts);
};
```